# Build an iphone file uploader

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am new to building iphone apps. Have been searching the net on how to create a file dialog. That will allow me to select either images or videos to be uploaded to a website.

If this was a .NET application I would use the FileDialog on my winforms view.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `UINavigationController`, `UITableViewController` and `NSFileManager` classes for building a file system browser, which reads the contents of the app's `~/Documents` folder and allows "drilling down" into subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a UITableView for holding files, NSFileManager for learning how to manipulate files stored on the iPhone, and then using HTML POST requests (depending on the site) to push the data to the site. Go find these in the developer documentation!

Comment: Found the answer is to use UIImagePickerController